# update_or_create me intenta guardar un objeto nuevo en vez de actualizar

Tags: django, orm

como va? Tengo el siguiente inconveniente con el ORM  de Django.

Tengo la siguiente clase

```
class FasTeorico(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField(primary_key=True)
    producto = models.ForeignKey('ProductosFasTeorico', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='producto')
    embarque = models.CharField(max_length=45, primary_key=True)
    
    prima_fob_c_centxbushel = models.FloatField(db_column='prima_FOB_C_centXbushel', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    prima_fob_v_centxbushel = models.FloatField(db_column='prima_FOB_V_centXbushel', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    prima_fob_promedio_centxbushel = models.FloatField(db_column='prima_FOB_promedio_centXbushel', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fob_c_dolarxtn = models.FloatField(db_column='FOB_C_dolarXtn', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fob_v_dolarxtn = models.FloatField(db_column='FOB_V_dolarXtn', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fob_mercado_dolarxtn = models.FloatField(db_column='FOB_mercado_dolarXtn', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    posicion_cbot = models.CharField(db_column='posicion_CBOT', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    precio_cbot_centxbushel = models.FloatField(db_column='precio_CBOT_centXbushel', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    precio_cbot_dolarxtn = models.FloatField(db_column='precio_CBOT_dolarxTn', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fob_oficial = models.FloatField(db_column='FOB_oficial', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    alicuota_derecho_exportacion = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    derechos_exportacion = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    gastos_fobbing = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    gastos_comerciales = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    gastos_fob = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    recupero_pellets = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    gastos_industrializacion = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    gastos_totales = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    fas_teorico = models.FloatField(db_column='FAS_teorico', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'FAS_Teorico'
        unique_together = (('fecha', 'producto', 'embarque'),)
```

Y cuando intento utilizar el update_or_create() me devuelve el error: "1062, "Duplicate entry '2021-05-18-2-MAY21' for key 'PRIMARY'"

El código que intento ejecutar es el siguiente:

```
obj, val = FasTeorico.objects.update_or_create(
                        fecha = vFecha,
                        producto = idProducto2,
                        embarque = vEmbarque,
                        defaults = {
                            'prima_fob_c_centxbushel': prima_FOB_C_cxbu,
                            'prima_fob_v_centxbushel': prima_FOB_V_cXbu,
                            'prima_fob_promedio_centxbushel': prima_FOB_promedio_cXbu,
                            'fob_c_dolarxtn': fob_C_usd_tn,
                            'fob_v_dolarxtn': fob_V_usd_tn,
                            'fob_mercado_dolarxtn': fob_Mercado,
                            'posicion_cbot': posicion_CBOT,
                            'precio_cbot_centxbushel': precio_CBOT_cbu,
                            'fob_oficial': fob_oficial,
                            'alicuota_derecho_exportacion': params_alicuotaDerechosExportador,
                            'derechos_exportacion': derechosDeExportador,
                            'gastos_fobbing': gastosFobbing,
                            'gastos_comerciales': gastosComerciales,
                            'gastos_fob': gastosFOB,
                            'gastos_totales': gastosTotales,
                            'fas_teorico': fasTeoricoMaiz
                        }
                    )
```

Cuando quiero hacer una modificación, me genera ese error. Es decir, cuando envío los parámetros de "fecha, producto, embarque" que ya existen, lanza ese error en vez de realizar la actualización.

Intenta hacer un Insert en la BD en vez de un Update.

Me podrán ayudar?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema viene desde tu modelo, ya que estas usando el campo fecha y embarque como llave primaria. La llave primaria siempre debe de ser única, en el caso del campo fecha podrías tener muchos objetos con la misma fecha entonces no se respetaría la unicidad de la llave primaria por lo que no es viable como lo estas haciendo. Simplemente deja de usar esos campos como llave primaria y deja por defecto el que usa el models.Model (entero autoincremental). Ya con eso no deberías de tener problemas.

```
class FasTeorico(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField() # sin llave primaria
    producto = models.ForeignKey('ProductosFasTeorico', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='producto')
    embarque = models.CharField(max_length=45) # sin llave primaria
    
    prima_fob_c_centxbushel = models.FloatField(db_column='prima_FOB_C_centXbushel', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    prima_fob_v_centxbushel = models.FloatField(db_column='prima_FOB_V_centXbushel', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    prima_fob_promedio_centxbushel = models.FloatField(db_column='prima_FOB_promedio_centXbushel', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fob_c_dolarxtn = models.FloatField(db_column='FOB_C_dolarXtn', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fob_v_dolarxtn = models.FloatField(db_column='FOB_V_dolarXtn', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fob_mercado_dolarxtn = models.FloatField(db_column='FOB_mercado_dolarXtn', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    posicion_cbot = models.CharField(db_column='posicion_CBOT', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    precio_cbot_centxbushel = models.FloatField(db_column='precio_CBOT_centXbushel', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    precio_cbot_dolarxtn = models.FloatField(db_column='precio_CBOT_dolarxTn', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fob_oficial = models.FloatField(db_column='FOB_oficial', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    alicuota_derecho_exportacion = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    derechos_exportacion = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    gastos_fobbing = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    gastos_comerciales = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    gastos_fob = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    recupero_pellets = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    gastos_industrializacion = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    gastos_totales = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    fas_teorico = models.FloatField(db_column='FAS_teorico', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'FAS_Teorico'
        unique_together = (('fecha', 'producto', 'embarque'),)
```

Comment: Hola Kevin! Primero que nada, gracias por tu tiempo y tu respuesta. Entiendo lo que decís, pero es que en realidad mi clave primaria son esos 3 datos, es decir, no puede repetirse ninguno de los 3 al mismo tiempo, es una clave primaria compuesta. 
Como debería manejar esta situación? Mi ID de esa tabla es  fecha + producto + embarque

Comment: No creo que sea necesario una clave compuesta, si solo quieres que no se repitan los 3 al mismo tiempo con el unique_together deberia ser suficiente ya que estas validando que la combinación de ('fecha', 'producto', 'embarque') no se repita.

Comment: Kevin, muchas gracias, ya comprendí lo que me dijiste. El unique_together me da la integridad que necesito, y después lo maneja por el id automático.